# symfony2 installation instruction help please

Tags: symfony

doc root:

```
root@helloise:/var/www/symfony2# ls -lah
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K 2012-01-11 10:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K 2012-01-11 09:52 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   36 2012-01-11 10:04 web -> /home/helloises/symfony2/Symfony/web
root@helloise:/var/www/symfony2#
```

AND:

```
helloises@helloise:~/symfony2/Symfony$ ls -lah
total 48K
drwxr-xr-x  7 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-11 11:09 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-11 10:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-06 08:56 app
drwxr-xr-x  2 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-06 08:56 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 helloises helloises 1.6K 2012-01-06 08:56 deps
-rw-r--r--  1 helloises helloises  830 2012-01-06 08:56 deps.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 helloises helloises 1.1K 2012-01-06 08:56 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 helloises helloises 6.3K 2012-01-06 08:56 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  2 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-06 08:57 src
drwxr-xr-x 13 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-11 10:01 vendor
drwxr-xr-x  3 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-11 11:13 web
```

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/helloises/symfony2/Symfony/web"
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "/home/helloises/symfony2/Symfony/web">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
</Directory>

Alias /sf /home/helloises/symfony2/Symfony/...
<Directory "/home/helloises/symfony2/Symfony/....">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

thanks

Comment: Is that a question? :/ 

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

Comment: i edited the post..it was a question at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your HTTPD. Apache example: `DocumentRoot "/opt/webapps/Symfony/web`

Or

Put it anywhere and symlink /Symfony/web to /your/www/path/something

Comment: i have git installed so will unpack the "without vendors" download :)

Comment: i unpacked it and made the symlink. i am reading the readme and can check my configuration online on: http://localhost/Symfony/web/config.php. i installed in http://localhost/symfony/Symfony/web/config.php but get a 404 now?

Comment: I don't understand your issue now. If you can access config.php, then it's ok. Try http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php

Comment: the thing is i cant! i get 404 error on both: The requested URL /symfony/Symfony/web/apps_dev.php was not found on this server. i have a sub directory symfony that i created and unpacked in there :(

Comment: `$ ls -lah` your doc root please

Comment: nope i uncpacked into symfony2 directory and within THAT directory i have Symfony/web/apps_dev.php      http://localhost/symfony2/Symfony/web/apps_dev.php still gives 404 url not found

Comment: i clicked on your link here and got: The requested URL /symfony2 was not found on this server.  yikes what am i doing wrong?

Comment: check your web-server config if /var/www/ is your doc root

Comment: i posted it on top, is the alias and alias directory necessary?

Comment: im not sure but i have git installed and by accident installed the normal,standard version thus not the one "without vendors" can this be a problem? i unfortunately still sit with the same errors/problems...sorry...

Comment: Symfony_Standard_2.0.9.tgz as to Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.0.9.tgz

Comment: I think now it's time to stop this long conversation. Try to do it yourself. These are just basics, simple things...